# Bazooka blast ev3 Mindstorms using Python

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming, python

I would like to shoot balls with the ev3 Lego robot. How can I code it using Python?

Which components do I need for that and which function and motor use ?

Answer (score 2):

[ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org/) works pretty well for that purpose, and all you need is a microSD card.

You'll need to use the [Motor](http://ev3dev-lang.readthedocs.io/projects/python-ev3dev/en/stable/motors.html) class. It work with both large and medium motors, and either can be use to shoot balls, so this part will be at your preference.